# .net safely handle unhandled exception in non-forms and non-WPF app

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception

I have an application that interfaces with a 3rd party .NET DLL. My application doesn't use Windows Forms and is not WPF. Essentially there is no .NET UI thread. The 3rd party functionality is all handled in separate background threads.

Even though there isn't any UI component, the DLL uses a dispatcher to asynchronously process events. The problem I have is that there is a bug in the 3rd party DLL which throws an unhandled exception within one of their own internal event handlers that I have no control over.

There is a reasonable workaround I can follow to safely restart the functionality if I can safely catch this exception and detect the problem. But, since this is unhandled, the application just blows up.

Is there a way that I can catch this exception and still continue the application? Unfortunately I can't simply put a try/catch around it, since this is not happening in my code. The only thing I've found so far is the AppDomain UnhandledException event, but from what I can tell there is no way to recover the application from this.

Simplified, the background thread looks like this:

```
void mymanagedclass::threadproc()
{
    try
    {
        thedispatcher->Run();
    }
    catch(System::Exception^ e)
    {
        // Handle Exception here
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried putting a try/catch around the entire thread that calls the dispatcher, but it is never hit.

Comment: No, this requires a telephone, not code.  Call the owner of the code and ask for help.

Comment: What exception does the DLL throw? If it's a [corrupted state exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) then no workaround can help. Also, assuming you are instantiating a class exposed by the DLL, is it a single or multiple instances? If the problem is that the DLL isn't thread safe, you might be able to work around this by using a single instance at a time.

Comment: I completely agree with you Hans. Contacting them was the first thing I did. Unfortunately it'll be easier to implement a workaround then to get it fixed.

Comment: groverboy, I'm actually not sure what exception it is. So far I have not been able to trap it to identify it. It doesn't even hit the AppDomain.UnhandledException handler. Looking at the event log it appears to originate from a call to a function inside kernelbase.dll. I imagine somewhere down the line it's calling a WIN32 API function with invalid parameters.

Comment: OK I was able to identify it after all. Using a much simpler test program the AppDomain.UnhandledException actually gets hit. It is a Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

Comment: TargetInvocationException is a wrapper for the actual error, i.e. an _inner exception_. If you want to investigate, look at the exception stack trace that follows this preamble: "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details. --->"  Btw use the "@GKarRacer" notation to have SO notify the person that you replied.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into

[AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application. If sufficient information about the state of the application is available, other actions may be undertaken — such as saving program data for later recovery. Caution is advised, because program data can become corrupted when exceptions are not handled.

Note the cautionary statement.  Be sure that the 3rd party library is in a resumable state.

**UPDATE**

You should be able to run the 3rd party code in a separate app domain.  The unhandled exception will tear down the separate app domain, but I believe your application will continue to run.  You can use the otherAppDomain.UnhandledException handler to know when the other app domain needs to be restarted.

http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/executing-code-in-a-separate-application-domain-using-c-sharp.aspx

Comment: I saw that handler, but how do I prevent the application from terminating?

Comment: @You should be able to use a separate app domain to run the 3rd party code.  I updated my answer.

Comment: That looks quite interesting. I will check it out. In the meantime I can add one more wrinkle. I tried putting in the standard AppDomain.UnhandledException handler and it never got hit. The app goes straight to the generic Windows exception dialog and terminates. I then tested by throwing my own exception and that was seen by the handler, so at least the handler was correct.

Comment: Yes, it is managed. Actually this is the only reason I'm dealing with .NET code at all here. My application is actually native and compiled as managed just to interface with this library.